# Plot average curve for multiple graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm a beginner in matplotlib.
I've already created some graphs from a dataframe.
Now I want to create the average graph from multiple graphs.

Can anyone help me with this?

My graphs look like this:

```
alb = df[df.location == 'Albania']
bel = df[df.location == 'Belarus']
bih = df[df.location == 'Bosnia and Herzegovina']
blg = df[df.location == 'Bulgaria']
cro = df[df.location == 'Croatia']
hun = df[df.location == 'Hungary']
kos = df[df.location == 'Kosovo']
mld = df[df.location == 'Moldova']
mng = df[df.location == 'Montenegro']
nmc = df[df.location == 'North Macedonia']
pol = df[df.location == 'Poland']
rom = df[df.location == 'Romania']
rus = df[df.location == 'Russia']
srb = df[df.location == 'Serbia']
tur = df[df.location == 'Turkey']
ukr = df[df.location == 'Ukraine']

plt.plot(alb.date, alb.new_deaths_per_million)
plt.plot(bel.date, bel.new_deaths_per_million)
plt.plot(bih.date, bih.new_deaths_per_million)
plt.plot(blg.date, blg.new_deaths_per_million)
plt.plot(cro.date, cro.new_deaths_per_million)
plt.plot(hun.date, hun.new_deaths_per_million)
plt.plot(kos.date, kos.new_deaths_per_million)
plt.plot(mld.date, mld.new_deaths_per_million)
plt.plot(mng.date, mng.new_deaths_per_million)
plt.plot(nmc.date, nmc.new_deaths_per_million)
plt.plot(pol.date, pol.new_deaths_per_million)
plt.plot(rom.date, rom.new_deaths_per_million)
plt.plot(rus.date, rus.new_deaths_per_million)
plt.plot(srb.date, srb.new_deaths_per_million)
plt.plot(tur.date, tur.new_deaths_per_million)
plt.plot(ukr.date, ukr.new_deaths_per_million)
plt.legend(['Albania', 'Belarus', 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', 'Bulgaria', 'Croatia', 'Hungary', 'Kosovo', 'Moldova', 'Montenegro', 'North Macedonia', 'Poland', 'Romania', 'Russia', 'Serbia', 'Turkey', 'Ukraine'])
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [12, 8]
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 200
plt.show()
```

The graphs look like this:

[image]

Now I would like to create the average curve from all these graphs.
How can this be done?

Thanks for the help

This is the dataset I use:

```
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url,error_bad_lines=False)
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
display(df)
```

Comment: are the dates aligned? If so just average the data. Otherwise you will have to align the data first so you can calculate averages.

Comment: Can you share your dataset? It's hard to guess the best solution without seeing the data.

Comment: If you are looking for average of each data point , you can loop through all data points in the lists get the average and then plot using the average list. so something like this `ndpm = [ [alb.new_deaths_per_million[i], bel.new_deaths_per_million[i]...... , ukr.new_deaths_per_million[i]] for i in range(len(alb.new_deaths_per_million))]` then `avg_list = [sum(x)/16 for element in ndpm]`

Comment: @MaximilianPeters the dataset is added now to the question

Answer (score 0):

- Put your countries in an array, it makes your life easier, your code shorter and easier to maintain
- I would convert the dates to `datetime` objects and then get the weekly average. The graph looks less noisy and is easier to interpret. Calculating the average with missing values is also tricky.

  `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`

  `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W', key='date'))['new_deaths_per_million'].mean().reset_index()`
- Then group your data by `date` and calculate the mean. The mean values can the be plotted.

[image]

```
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(url,error_bad_lines=False)
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

    countries = ['Albania', 'Belarus', 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', 'Bulgaria', 'Croatia', 'Hungary', 'Kosovo', 'Moldova', 'Montenegro', 'North Macedonia', 'Poland', 'Romania', 'Russia', 'Serbia', 'Turkey', 'Ukraine']


    for country in countries:
        df_country = df[df.location == country].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W', key='date'))['new_deaths_per_million'].mean().reset_index()
        assert len(df_country) > 0
        plt.plot(df_country.date, df_country.new_deaths_per_million)

    df_countries = df[df.location.isin(countries)].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W', key='date'))['new_deaths_per_million'].mean().reset_index()

    plt.plot(df_countries['date'], df_countries['new_deaths_per_million'], linewidth=4)
    plt.legend([*countries, 'average'])

    plt.show()
```

Comment: I tried this but I still don't get the right curve.
Could you help with the dataset I added to the comment below?

Comment: This is the dataset I use for the analysis:
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url,error_bad_lines=False)
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
display(df)

Comment: @AdmirRamic: Have a look at the updated answer